# Exporting SQL table using phpMyAdmin gives no results for large data sets

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

When I open my table in phpMyAdmin and click *Export* (selecting .zip from the save-as options), I get an empty (0 byte) zip file. The table has ~200 000 records. This problem does not occur for smaller tables. This problem also does not occur when I export only the first 60 000 records.

Is this a bandwidth limitation? Is this something in my settings for MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is potentially not a MySQL but a PHP problem, you might be exceeding the [memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) for a PHP script, try increasing `memory_limit` in the `php.ini`.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can directly exporting by using cmd in the dir of that database instead of exporting using the phpMyAdmin UI.

```
C:>mysql -u username -p password database_name < filename.sql
```